# Hex code not working for Less than '<' sign in HTML unless a space is given next to it

Tags: html, unicode

I have the following JSON injected into HTML as a content. The value for the `codex` is expected to be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

All the keyboard keys with HEX code works fine except `&#x3e;` unless a space is given next to it, and it looks like `< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

**Actual json content**

```json
  {
    "number": 8,
    "tool": "MAVEN",
    "tip": "default .m2 settings.xml",
    "codex": "&#x3e; ?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&#x3e;"
  }
```

How it looks now:

```xml
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    < mirrors>
    < mirror>
        < id>central< /id>
        < name>central< /name>
        < url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/< /url>
        < mirrorOf>maven_central< /mirrorOf>
    < /mirror>
    < /mirrors>
< /settings>
```

What is expected:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>central</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <mirrorOf>maven_central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Comment: What does "injected" mean? Where's the code that handles this "injection"?

Comment: @NicoHaase thats the light weight website I am building - if you check snippet #8 & click 'view snippet' https://prashanth-sams.github.io/snippets-101/

Comment: https://github.com/prashanth-sams/snippets-101

Comment: As usual: please add all neccessary information to your question by editing. Nobody can guess how you "inject" the data into the markup

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use the HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of their hex values? Like you are using the `&quot;` entity for `"`

Comment: @RemyLebeau same issue when I use `&lt;`

Comment: If you still need help, please explain what "injected into HTML as a content" means. If there is any code involved that handles this "injection", please add it to your question by editing

Answer (score -1):

greater than sign in hex is `&#x3e;`

less than sign in hex is `&#x3C;`trying using it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this change remove the spaces?

Comment: how much more explanation is needed? hes attempting to open and close with a greater than sign. Thanks for the thumbs down though.

Comment: Any would be fine. How does changing from one to another character resolve the problem of the additional spaces?

Comment: @norcaljohnny as said in the question, I used this hex code but I need to put a space to make it work. Giving a space actually breaks the code